# Dynamic Mapping Disabled is not working in ElasticSearch

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, dynamic-mapping

I am running into errors when I try to disable dynamic mapping in ElasticSearch settings. I am using ElasticSearch 1.7 version for implementation.

StackTrace :

```
8151 [main] WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild - Exception running child : org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: Found unrecoverable error [10.74.51.71:9200] returned Not Found(404) - [TypeMissingException[[test_2017051222] type[[vehicle, trying to auto create mapping, but dynamic mapping is disabled]] missing]]; Bailing out..
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.retryFailedEntries(RestClient.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.bulk(RestClient.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.tryFlush(RestRepository.java:225)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.flush(RestRepository.java:248)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.doWriteToIndex(RestRepository.java:187)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.writeToIndex(RestRepository.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.write(EsOutputFormat.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Settings snippet :

```
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.query.default_field":"test",
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s",
    "index.mapper.dynamic": false ,
    "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "ngram_filter": {
               "type": "ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 18,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "ngram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "ngram_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
  }
```

I am seeing that dynamic mapping is disabled in settings on ES endpoint but the job fails. I have a avro json mapping file and es json mapping file where avro json mapping file is the superset while es json mapping file is subset. I do not want all the fields in the superset mapping file to be reflected on ES index instead only dump fields which are in subset mapping file. Am I doing it wrong or is there any other way of doing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have set  `"index.mapper.dynamic": false` which means new types will not be created automatically without first declaring them.

What you would want to do is set `"dynamic": "false"` in the mapping of your type.

    `PUT /test_index
    {
      "mappings": {
        "test_type": {
          "dynamic": "false"
        }
      }
    }`

For more Info:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/dynamic-mapping.html

Example:

1. Run Mapping

   `PUT /my_index
   {
     "mappings": {
       "testing": {
         "dynamic": "false",
         "properties": {
           "field1": {
             "type": "string",
             "index": "analyzed"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }`
2. Index the document in `testing` type

   `POST /my_index/testing/1
   {
     "field1":"demo",
     "field99":"anotherDemo"
   }`
3. Response of `GET /my_index/testing/_mapping`

   `{
     "my_index": {
       "mappings": {
         "testing": {
           "dynamic": "false",
           "properties": {
             "field1": {
               "type": "string"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }`

As you will see that there is no mapping for the field99.

Comment: `"mappings": {
    "testing": {
      "dynamic" : "false" ,
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "field3": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "field4": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "field5": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }`  Didn't work.

Comment: I have edited the post with an example. Hope that helps.